# SELECT sum but with where in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying sum up the `total_grand` column of my `orders` table.

So I have this query

```
SELECT sum(total_grand) as total 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE overall_status in ("In-Transit","Not Yet Shipped","Not Yet Validated");
```

It works fine. But I need to add new conditional statement.

Here's my sample `orders` table columns with data.

| total_grand | overall_status | televalidator_user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | In-Transit | 1 |
| 200 | Not Yet Shipped | 1 |
| 300 | Not Yet Validated | NULL |
| 400 | Not Yet Validated | 1 |
| 500 | In-Transit | 1 |
| --------------------- | ------------------ | ------------------ |

I'm trying to sum up the `total_grand` but if televalidator_user_id is `NULL`, It should not be added to the sump

Since there is null `televalidator_user_id` on `row 3`

**the output must be: 1200**

Comment: `AND televalidator_user_id is not null` This is really pretty basic stuff that you can get an answer to from a simple read of ANY SQL Manual. The manual should be your first port of call, not SO

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT sum(total_grand) as total 
    FROM `orders` 
    WHERE overall_status in ("In-Transit", "Not Yet Shipped", "Not Yet Validated") 
    AND televalidator_user_id is not null;
```